# Create an if statement with css

Tags: css, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is it possible in CSS  that when for example the class 'demo1' is `display:block` the  class 'demo2' is automatically `display:None`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer : **No**

Workaround : Use Javascript or jQuery using `.toggle()`

---

If you want to stick with CSS, you can do something like

```
div[style*="block"] + div {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvLvU/)

The above selector will see whether `div` having an attribute of `style` contains a value called `block` if yes, than hide the `adjacent` `div` element using `+`

Comment: Indeed, or use a higher-level class. e.g. `.hidden div.one, .hidden div.two { display: none; }` then apply `hidden` to a container of both divs.